# 聊天一会儿 or 聊一会儿天?

Tags: grammar

I thought it should be 聊一会儿天, since the measure words should be put right after the verb, like in 吃一点儿东西，参观一次长城. But there are a lot more results of 聊天一会儿 on Google. (74,200 vs 18,100)

Can someone explain why is that?

Thank you

Comment: 聊一会儿天 fits the pattern for 离合词 cf.＂现代汉语离合词用法词典＂：聊天儿：［离］（２）＂聊＂后带补语：我们刚坐下聊了一会儿天儿，他家就来了几位客人,
do all the  聊天一会儿 results really have this sequence?, search results for a particular sequence usually include rearrangements and broken sequences

Comment: Yeah, maybe that's the case. Thx

Answer (score 2):

“聊一会儿天” is the more commonly used version.

Searching on Google, some “聊天一会儿”'s results are like “来聊天一会儿删”, in which it is actually “来聊天，一会儿删”。

Using my Google, “聊一会儿天” shows more results in fact. (742,000 vs 705,000)

Comment: Try using quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

My Google search gave similar results (with quotes):

"聊天一会儿" (72,500 results)

"聊一会儿天" (14,600 results)

---

You are right that the 1st phrase is not correct. But let's take a closer look at some results:

> 一会儿和同事聊**聊天,一会儿**在QQ上和网友说说话。
>
> 为什么我在红米上qq只**聊天一会儿**就好了很多流量.
>
> 刚才哥儿几个**聊天**，中间我出去**一会儿**。回来后，大伙儿看我直乐.

---

See, by putting a comma or rearranging the words, they now have the correct syntax. Since these are more frequently used than `聊一会儿天` (at least in writing), Google found more articles, which makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

聊一会儿天 is correct, the "一" can be omitted in speaking.

More examples:
打(一)会儿游戏, 
看(一)会儿书,
听(一)会儿音乐.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the search result in context，聊天一会儿 may came from a piece of sentence which has the meaning other than “talk for a while”.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, most of the chinese in the world are come from china.
If you want to learn the original chinese, then **聊一会儿天** should be the correct one.

聊天一会儿 sounds weird because 聊 is the verb, 天 just a word which "supports" the verb。So instead we add 一会儿 right after 聊, not after the "support word"

Answer (score 0):

"聊天一会儿" is not Chinese sentence, no one say like that, "聊一会儿天" is people say all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 一会儿聊天。 
我要和她一会儿聊天。(I'm going to chat with her in a while). 
It sounds more natural. 
Like in English,  the order of word changes the whole signification of the sentence. 
一会儿 = time indicator
聊天＝Verb
You can also say 待会儿聊天，which has almost the same meaning.

Answer (score -1):

My font of all knowledge from  泰州 also immediately said: '聊一会儿天‘是对的。

She would not say: '聊天一会儿‘， but she can't say why not.

Answer (score -1):

The truth is, no native Chinese speakers say, 聊天一会儿, but 聊一会儿天. There is no explanation to any linguistic usage or grammar, unfortunately.

So, never say 聊天一会儿, but only 聊一会儿天? Maybe because 聊天 is a loose word or compound word, so you can say 聊什么天，never 聊天什么。

Comment: explanation: search web for ＂separable verb＂ and ＂离合词＂，also as OP says if 聊天 is considered as verb 聊 with object 天 then 聊一会儿天 simply agrees with rule for duration complements (时量补语）e.g. 我今天写了二十分钟（的）汉字。为了这件事，我们开了两个晚上（的）会。我们今年上了将近百天（的）课。小明打了一下午的球。昨天我们看了一天的电影。（examples from ＂实用现代汉语语法＂）

Answer (score -2):

聊天一会儿 is the correct one.

- 聊天= chit chat
- 一会儿 = a moment

聊一会儿天 is the incorrect one.

- 聊= talk, chat
- 一会儿 = a moment
- 天 = sky

The better ways to say it will be 聊聊，谈心，聊一下，说八卦。Don't use 儿 because it also means son, and because 儿 (er) is merely an accent for some part of China. it doesn't add any meaning to your sentence.

Comment: I am Chinese and I would say '聊(一)会儿天' instead of '聊天一会儿' despite of seemingly grammatical correctness of the latter one.